# spring data JPA association in Map

Tags: jpa, associations

I'm trying to use `Map` in Spring Data JPA to handle the relationship to store records of equipment quantity.
I followed this [guide](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/map-association-java-util-map/#workWithMap) to create the entity.

```
Meeting{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "meeting_id", updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private int id;

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "equipment_type")
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Map<EquipmentType, Integer> equipment = new HashMap<>();
}
```

`EquipmentType` is an `Enum`.

This is the table for the property:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS meeting_equipment (
  meeting_id           INTEGER     NOT NULL REFERENCES meeting (meeting_id),
  equipment_type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  quantity       INTEGER     NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Once I try to create a meeting entity, I get error `ERROR:column "meeting_meeting_id" of relation "meeting_equipment" does not exist`

May I know what's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Your table meeting_equipment does not match what JPA is expecting.
It has a column `meeting_id` but your JPA implementation expects `meeting_meeting_id`

Either rename the column to the expected `meeting_meeting_id` or configure your mapping to use the current column name. I think this might do the trick:

```
@JoinTable(joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="meeting_id")}
```

Of course, you probably can create your own naming strategy if you have many cases like this and want to keep your column names as they are.

Comment: Of course, if you "create your own naming strategy" then you are tying yourself to one particular JPA provider and become non-portable.

Comment: From the link that I provide, their table does not have double prefix and they didnt use `@JoinTable`, how to do it?

Comment: Yes, Thorben Janssen's article does have the `@JoinTable` annotation. I copied it from there for the answer.

Comment: I tried `@JoinTable`, it gives me `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @JoinTable.inverseJoinColumns targeting an unmapped class: Meeting.equipment[java.lang.Integer]`

Comment: After checking the JavaDoc it seems, I got that backward. Try `joinColumn` instead.